# Marching Cubes - Legalities?

Tags: legal

I know this isn't a "Is this legal" website, but because Marching Cubes is definitely a large subject in game development, and isn't really about a specific graphic/item, it would pass...

To the point!

Does anyone know whether Marching Cubes is allowed in a commercial game? If so is there anything i must do? Credit to someone/company etc?

Cheers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_cubes) says:

> This patent expired in 2005, and it is now legal for the graphics community to use it without royalties since more than 17 years have passed from its issue date (December 1, 1987[2]).

Still it's always a good idea to double-check with your lawyer.